# Warning: Object object has no method 'pluck' Use --force to continue

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, npm, gruntjs

I am working on an Application developed in Asp.Net with Angular.

While running my project using inetmgr, My angular is not working.
Then I checked in Task runner, Then get following error.

> cmd.exe /c grunt -b "D:\DevProjects\LogisticMonitor\trunk\CcxTLM.Web" --gruntfile "D:\DevProjects\LogisticMonitor\trunk\CcxTLM.Web\Gruntfile.js" default
>   Running "clean:files" (clean) task
>   **Warning: Object object has no method 'pluck' Use --force to continue.
>   Process terminated with code 3.
>   Aborted due to warnings.**

Comment: Are you getting any 404s in your network passage? this is either pluck from _ or pluck from grunt pluck

Comment: Can you add the code for your `Gruntfile.js` to the question post?

Comment: No, I am not getting any 404 in my console log but concatenate file app.all.min.js is not building successfully as it is throwing the error.

Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module config due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'config' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: concat: {
            './app/app.all.min.js': ["./app/**/*.js"]
        },
        uglify: {
            development: {
                options: {
                    mangle: false,
                    compress: {
                        drop_console: true }
                },
                files: {
                    './app/app.all.min.js': ["./app/**/*.js"]
                }
            },build: {
                options: {
                    mangle: false,
                    compress: {
                        drop_console: true
                    }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed latest versions of all dependies in package.json. Then Build the project.
It fixed for me.